# SQL query deleting all rows instead of specific row

Tags: php, sql, axios

```
foreach ($toRemove as $remove){
            $sql = "DELETE FROM orders WHERE productId = :productId AND invoiceNo = :invoiceNo AND quantity = :quantity";
            $stmt = $pdo1->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam('productId', $remove[0], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam('invoiceNo', $invoice->invoiceNo, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam('quantity', $remove[1], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
```

`$remove` structure: `['productId', 'quantity']`

`'productId'` is a string eg. `'C-1'`

I expected this query to only remove 1 row, however, it is removing all rows that has `'productId'` with `'C-x'` format. This query works fine when `'productId'` is purely an 'int', without the C in front, however, due to requirements, I cannot remove the C as it represents a custom product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to identify productId as a string for PDO param binder.
Replace this:

```
$stmt->bindParam('productId', $remove[0], PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

With

```
$stmt->bindParam('productId', $remove[0], PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

For reading: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php

Comment: damn how did I miss this, spent hours trying to figure out what was going on, tyvm!